# Qml window with a MouseArea which transfers focus to its parent

Tags: qt, qml

I want to create a window for playing video on a portion of the application window. It should have a MouseArea functioning properly but transfer focus to its parent (`ApplicationWindow`) when clicked on it as if clicked on its parent. Currently, I set the flags as the following;

```
flags: Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowDoesNotAcceptFocus | Qt.WindowStaysOnBottomHint
```

By setting Qt.WindowDoesNotAcceptFocus flag, the window does not accept focus but does not pass focus to its parent either. If I set the `Qt.WindowTransparentForInput` window does pass focus to its parent, however, all MouseAreas on that window are being disabled.

I checked [Qt WindowType Flags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum) but couldn't find a workaround. Does any of you guys propose a solution to this?

Comment: I don't think thats possible from QML alone, as windows are managed by the OS. Either a window gets the input or it doesn't. The OS does not care, what the stuff inside the window does with it. You will propably have to extend the window class from C++, capture those events there and send the programatically to the other window.

Comment: What is the `parent`. And do you want to transfer the focus to the parent, or to have the click event in both things?

Comment: `parent` is the application window. I want to get click events only in this window and pass focus to the application window.

Comment: If I got you right by now, you also want to handle mouse events in two windows simultaneously. For this you can use an eventfilter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess in the dark - you want to have something like this:

```
Window {
    id: win
    width: 600
    height: 600
    visible: true

    ApplicationWindow {
        id: someWin
        property Window parentWin: win
        width: 600
        height: 300
        visible: true
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                someWin.parentWin.requestActivate()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

If not, please clarify what you mean with "transfer focus", or what exactly you try to achieve. Consider images and code examples to help our imagination to understand your problem.

Comment: Transferring focus maybe wasn't a good description of what I want to achieve and sorry about that. I am already using your solution and it works, thank you for helping. Your solution achieves most of my problems but I want to reduce my code size and try to accomplish a more natural, embedded window inside a window.

Comment: For example, this solution does not work when there are menus in both the parent and the child window, menus can simultaneously remain open. In order to solve this I also need to mimic the click effect, simply the program should behave I clicked on parent window when I click on the child. Besides, there could be other problems in the future that I cannot foresee at the moment.

Comment: I cannot forsee your future problems either. Pick one specific problem, get one specific answer. When new peoblems arise, ask again